# How to verify a public(facebook's) key ? and then sign and trust them

Tags: security, encryption, gpg, cryptography

Recently I enabled gpp emails option in facebook. Then they sent me a test mail to check whether I'm able to decrypt that or not.
So first I downloaded there public key from [Here](https://www.facebook.com/facebook/publickey/download/) and imported in my key ring by

`gpg --import < facebook.asc`

Then  I did

`gpg --decrypt encryped.asc`

encryped.asc (It's message file name).
It **decrypted the message** well. But in addition it said.

```
.......
gpg: Good signature from "Facebook, Inc." [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 31A7 0953 D8D5 90BA 1FAB  3776 2F38 98CE DEE9 58CF
     Subkey fingerprint: 896B E2D0 C09A 5624 73CC  43C6 0EFA 0776 3A08 919E
.....
```

How i can remove this warning . As facebook is not my neighbour,that I can call them and ask for their finger print. How I'm supposed to remove this warning. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is a way for you to meaningfully verify this key in the traditional web-of-trust sense.

However you can use the “trust on first use” model instead:

```
gpg2 --tofu-policy good 31A70953D8D590BA1FAB37762F3898CEDEE958CF
```

Verifying the signature with `--trust-model tofu` will no longer show a warning.

See [Trouble verifying linux, even after downloading key I get "No public key"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607615/86440) for links.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `gpg --edit-key` function [per the gpg man-page](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html) and use the `trust` command.  In this case 2F3898CEDEE958CF is the last 16 hex-digits of the fingerprint you imported.

```
$ gpg --edit-key 2F3898CEDEE958CF

gpg> trust
pub  rsa4096/2F3898CEDEE958CF
     created: 2015-05-17  expires: 2022-05-21  usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
[ unknown] (1). Facebook, Inc.

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify 
other users' keys (by looking at passports, checking fingerprints 
from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 3

pub  rsa4096/2F3898CEDEE958CF
     created: 2015-05-17  expires: 2022-05-21  usage: SC  
     trust: marginal      validity: unknown

gpg> quit
```