# Meaning of gpg output

Tags: linux-mint

I just downloaded an iso image of Linux Mint. Upon checking the steps for [verification](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verify.html), I obtain

```
$ gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt
gpg: Signature made Thu 08 Jul 2021 05:06:26 AM CDT using RSA key ID A25BAE09
gpg: Good signature from "Linux Mint ISO Signing Key <root@linuxmint.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 27DE B156 44C6 B3CF 3BD7  D291 300F 846B A25B AE09
```

What does it mean that one has a good signature but that the key is not certified with a trusted signature?

Answer (score 2):

The “good signature” message means that the signature is valid, *i.e.* that the private key matching whatever public key you have locally did indeed sign the file.

The “not certified” message means that you haven’t verified that the key itself matches the identity it claims. This is tied to the “web of trust” and is considered impractical nowadays for most people.

See [Trouble verifying linux, even after downloading key I get "No public key"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607615/86440) for details. If you follow the instructions there to enable “trust on first use” you will no longer get the “not certified” message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why you mention that it is impractical nowadays? Also the manual in your link says `When compared with the Web of Trust, TOFU offers significantly weaker security guarantees.` Then what's the best way to follow?

Comment: It’s impractical for a number of reasons. The web of trust relies on key signatures, but most keyservers no longer transmit those (other than the self-signature required to establish identity and expiry dates). Even if you have signatures in your keyring, building a web of trust requires assigning trust to individual keys, which is typically done by meeting their owners (for example at key signing parties); even without the pandemic that’s a hefty requirement!

Comment: +1, Thanks for this explanation :-)